# PySide2 display same icon in file dialog as main window

Tags: python, pyside2, qfiledialog

I have a simple pyside2 application which looks kinda like this:

```
import sys
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog, QPushButton, QFileDialog, QVBoxLayout
from PySide2 import QtGui

class Form(QDialog):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Form, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("My Form")
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("myicon.png"))
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.button = QPushButton("Open dialog")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.browse)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def browse(self):
        qfd = QFileDialog()
        qfd.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("myicon.png"))
        filename, _ = qfd.getOpenFileName(None, "Load Data", ".", "*.txt")



if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Create the Qt Application
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    # Create and show the form
    form = Form()
    form.show()
    # Run the main Qt loop
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I want to setup the same icon for the `QFileDialog` as the main window icon but for some reason it does not work. Is there a way to set it like I'm trying above? Thanks for ideas, pointers and help in advance! (I'm using Ubuntu 20.04)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The getOpenFileName method is a static method that creates an internal QFileDialog other than "qfd" so the icon is not applied. One possible option is not to use getOpenFileName but to create the logic only using the QFileDialog class, and another solution is to access the QFileDialog object created inside getOpenFileName using the characteristic that is a toplevel:

```py
import sys

from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Form(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Form, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("My Form")
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("myicon.png"))
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Open dialog")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.browse)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)

    def browse(self):
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, self.handle_timeout)
        filename, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(
            None,
            "Load Data",
            ".",
            "*.txt",
            options=QtWidgets.QFileDialog.DontUseNativeDialog,
        )

    def handle_timeout(self):
        for w in QtWidgets.QApplication.topLevelWidgets():
            if isinstance(w, QtWidgets.QFileDialog):
                w.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon("myicon.png"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    form = Form()
    form.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: For some reason the code snippet does not work for me on Ubuntu 20.04. The icon in the QFileDialog is still not the same as the main dialog window. How to create the logic using only QFileDialog class?

Comment: Yes this works! But why can't I use the NativeDialog window?

Comment: @Blind0ne I don't know, maybe it's a bug

Comment: Yes could be. But when using the DontUseNativeDialog flag the handle_timeout is not required. It automatically assigns the main window icon to the dialog window.